# How can I include null values in arithmetic query in django

Tags: python, django

I have the field called `surface_area` which is null and float.

Now I can't set that to `default 0` because 0 means something else in business rules.

I want to perform query like this

`Room.objects.filter(surface_area__lte=40)`

But this does not include null values.

How can I include null values as well for lte queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for `null` values like:

```
Room.objects.filter(surface_area__isnull=True)
```

And combine that with your `lte`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Room.objects.filter( Q(surface_area__lte=40) | Q(surface_area__isnull=True) )
```